# ACCESS: How to use compare German date time in access Query

Tags: ms-access

Whats wrong with this query?

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS WHERE [EDIT DATE] >#12.03.2015 10:47:35#
```

when i execute this query it show an error.

**Syntax error in date in query expression '[EDIT DATE] >#12.03.2015 10:47:35.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use either the US date format mm/dd/yyyy

```
[EDIT DATE] >#03/12/2015 10:47:35#
```

or the ISO format yyyy-mm-dd

```
[EDIT DATE] >#2015-03-12 10:47:35#
```